# Redirect grep error output inside if conditional

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, io-redirection

I have written a script to search an *.ini* file for some specific word.

The *.ini* file has one of two different names, (let's say *config.ini* or *configuration.ini*), so I have to check in both.

I am doing it with the following `if` sentences by using logical `OR`:

```
HAS_SOME_WORD=FALSE
if    [ "$(grep -v '^;\|^\[' "path_to_file/config.ini" | \
           grep -c '\\some_word')" -ge 1 ] \
   || [ "$(grep -v '^;\|^\[' "path_to_file/configuration.ini" | \          
          grep -c '\\some_word')" -ge 1 ]; then 
    HAS_SOME_WORD=TRUE
else
    HAS_SOME_WORD=FALSE
fi
```

I am avoiding the lines starting by *";"* or *"["* as they must not be included in the desired search, while looking for the word *"\some_word"*.

I want is to exclude the grep error messages when one of the two files does not exist, i.e:

```
grep: path_to_file/config.ini: No such file or directory
```

or:

```
grep: path_to_file/configuration.ini: No such file or directory
```

I have been able to avoid them by redirecting the output to `/dev/null` when executing the script:

```
./search_script.sh 2>/dev/null
```

However I would like to include this redirection in the `if` code itself, not when invoking the script.

How shall I implement that? Is there a more efficient way of doing what I'm trying?

I have tried to add the `-q` parameter to `grep` in order to avoid the error messages printed, but it had no effect. Also tried adding `2>/dev/null` redirection at the end of each `if` sentence, but I'm afraid that I haven't applied the correct syntax.

Comment: Adding a `2>/dev/null` redirection in each `if` branch *should* work.  Can you show us exactly what you tried?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I tried it as follows: `if    [ "$(grep -v '^;\|^\[' "path_to_file/config.ini" | \
           grep -c '\\some_word')" -ge 1 2>/dev/null ]; then` (For both if's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `grep` can search multiple files, and that `-v` and `-c` code can be simplified, try:

```
cd "path_to file"
if grep -qs '^[^;[].*\\some_word' config.ini configuration.ini ; then 
    # ...etc
fi
cd -
```

The `grep` options in long form:

```
grep --quiet --no-messages '^[^;[].*\\some_word' \
     config.ini configuration.ini
```

The OP code `-v` (or `--invert-match`) and 2nd `grep` are needless, because a regexp like `^[^;[]` can do it in one shot.  From `man grep`:

> A bracket expression is a list of characters enclosed by **[** and **]**.  It
>   matches any single character in that list; if the first character of
>   the list is the caret **^** then it matches any character **not** in the
>   list.

Answer (score 2):

The [other answer, suggesting `--no-messages`/`-s`,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341232/90751) is more appropriate for your problem, but the following will also work for commands that don't have a "silent" option.

## Redirecting the command

To redirect errors from a [simple command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Commands), you should put the redirection with that command, ie. in the same position in the pipeline:

```
if [ "$(grep -v '^;\|^\[' "path_to_file/config.ini" 2>/dev/null | \
  grep -c '\\some_word')" -ge 1 ] \
```

The first `grep` is the one generating the "No such file or directory" message, so that's the one that has to be redirected.

## Redirecting the pipeline

If multiple parts of the pipeline can generate errors, you could place the entire pipeline in a [group](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping), with a single redirection after it:

```
if [ "$( ( grep -v '^;\|^\[' "path_to_file/config.ini" | \
  grep -v -f "path_to_file/ignored_patterns" | \
  grep -c '\\some_word' )  2>/dev/null )" -ge 1 ] \
```

## Redirecting the conditional construct

You can redirect the whole of the `if` [construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) by putting the redirection after the closing `fi`:

```
if [ "$(grep -v '^;\|^\[' "path_to_file/config.ini" | \
    grep -c '\\some_word')" -ge 1 ] \
 ...
else
 ...
fi 2>/dev/null
```

This will redirect errors from all commands (both **test-** and **consequent-**) inside that block.